# Is it possible to have an routing app coverage polygon file (geojson) that covers the entire world?

Tags: ios, gps, mapkit

I am trying to have a geojson cover the entire world.  What would the geojson look like?

More specifically why is this wrongly formatted for itunes?

```
{
 "type": "MultiPolygon",
 "coordinates": [[[
 [-169.4,58.8],
 [-168.0,83.4], 
 [188.4,83.3], 
 [194.0,-72.8], 
 [-166.6,-73.6], 
 [-169.4,58.8], 
 [-169.4,58.8]
 ]]]
 }
```

Or how does something like become compatible for upload: 
https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json

Comment: What do you mean with "cover the whole world"? A polygon that has surrounds the world (this is easy), or 100 millions of streets defined in a geojson such that an app can route it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polygon, having legal coordinates, that surrounds the whole world, by means that a point in polygon algorithm will always return true for any given lat,lon coordinate, looks as follow:

It is a spherical rectangle with corner points at extreme longitude / latitude coordinates:

longitude: +/- 180.0
latitude +/- 90.0

The first coordinates is used again as the last point, to have a closed polygon, for applications that do not auto-close it.

The coordinates of that 4 point polygon are:

```
 "coordinates": [[[
 [-180.0, -90.0],
 [180.0, -90.0], 
 [180.0, 90.0], 
 [-180.0, 90.0], 
 [-180.0, -90.0]
 ]]]
```

It is a bit funny to understand how this "spherical rectangle" folds arround the world, sucht that both sides touches at the datum limit meridian.

It is easier to understand looking at a projected view of the world, as seen in the link in your answer (or at google maps)